# How can we get "estimated standard deviation" from MLE?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, standard-deviation

I'm looking for MLE as in the following picture.

[image]

I have some questions:

1. How can we get "the estimated standard deviation"?
2. Is "the estimated standard deviation" included in the output of the MLE?
3. What is the relationship between the likelihood function and "the estimated standard deviation"?
4. Are the empty red dots representing the observed data (distribution)? What do the red dots in the picture mean? How can we get them?

I need a step by step answer.

I havd referenced like here
https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.csail.mit.edu%2Fceliu%2Fdenoise%2Festnoise%2Fnoise_estimation_CVPR06.ppt&ei=PjpbVeznAYiT8QX_-IGoAw&usg=AFQjCNF6imR7VoxpOba8WhGVzvG2khcyrA&sig2=irolciWw9I9bUDZvANgcVQ&bvm=bv.93564037,d.dGc&cad=rjt

And here
http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/75593/Liu-CVPR06.pdf

Comment: Please provide a link to the rest of the document that contains this image. Without it, we cannot do any more than guess what the graphics mean.